# Symfony2 access POST (JSON)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, symfony

I have a form what jQuery sents for me using Ajax to php.

For this task I use following code:

```
        $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = { message: $('form').serialize() };
        console.log(form);
        $.post('{{ path('PUSChatBundle_add') }}', form, 'json');
```

This is what firebug sees in the request:

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
message message=Hi+stackoverflowers
Source
message=message%3DHi%2Bstackoverflowers
```

So and now to Symfony:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

    $message = new Message();
    $message->setText($data);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($message);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Success');
}
```

For somehow PHP does not manage to decode the json to a PHP-Array.

Regards,
B.Kaiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of all evil:

I sent the json threw a php json-validator and I became syntax error.

Strange because jQuery rendered the json
    var form = $('form').serializeArray();

I now only have to find what in detail is going wrong

Comment: So to solve the issue you have to use:
    var form = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray());

weird that this is not mentioned in any doc directly, however now it works :D

Answer (score 3):

Try `$request->getParameter('message');`.

Comment: var form = $('form').serializeArray();
            console.log(form);

            jQuery.ajax ({
                url: '{{ path('PUSChatBundle_add') }}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: form,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
        });

    });
</script>

Comment: Hi both solutions don't work:

        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        $message = new Message();
        $message->setText($data['name']);
        var_dump($data['name']);
        var_dump($request->getParameter('value'));

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $('form').serializeArray();
            console.log(form);

            jQuery.ajax ({
                url: '{{ path('PUSChatBundle_add') }}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: form,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
        });

    });

Comment: @user1246987, use `$data=$request->getParameter('message');` instead of `$data = json_decode($request->getContent());`

Comment: In Symfony2 there is no getParameter
See here: https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php

Comment: Sorry, correct one would be `$data = $this->request->get('message')`

Comment: @m2mdas `$request` comes from the parameter.